# List variables change both assigned in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, list

Using VS C# winform .NET 4.0.

I am quite new at c#.I have a program that checks for available times using a `DateTimePicker` and ComboBoxes.
The Binary list `AppVars._EventList` has no values so it is irrelevant.

My problem is with the Lists `sTimes`,`sT`&`sE`. When I change `cbxStartTime` to say `06:00` it removes the string 05 not just from `sT` but from all the lists. This result has the effect that if a new date is picked the `05` time slot will not be there.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
List<string> sTimes = new List<string>() { "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22" };
    List<string> sE;

    private void dtpStartDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbxEndTime.Items.Clear();
        cbxStartTime.Items.Clear();
        List<string> sT = sTimes;
        foreach (Events evt in AppVars._EventList)
            foreach (string s in sT)
                if (evt.StartDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") == dtpStartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") && evt.StartDateTime.Hour.ToString("HH") == s)
                    sT.Remove(s);
        int iSmall = Convert.ToInt32(sT[0]);
        foreach (string s in sT)
        {
            cbxStartTime.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s) + ":00");
            if (iSmall + 1 == Convert.ToInt32(s))
                iSmall++;
        }
        for (int s = Convert.ToInt32(sT[0]); s <= iSmall + 1; s++)
            cbxEndTime.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s) + 1 + ":00");
        if (cbxStartTime.Items.Count == 0)
            epdTime.SetError(cbxStartTime, "No Time slots available for this day");
        sE = sT;
    }

    private void cbxStartTime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> sT = sE;
        cbxEndTime.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string item in sT.ToList())//change happens here
            if (Convert.ToDateTime("2001/01/01 " + cbxStartTime.SelectedItem) > Convert.ToDateTime("2001/01/01 " + item + ":00"))
                sT.Remove(item);
        int iSmall = Convert.ToInt32(sT[0]);
        foreach (string s in sT)
            if (iSmall + 1 == Convert.ToInt32(s))
                iSmall++;
        for (int s = Convert.ToInt32(sT[0]); s <= iSmall; s++)
            cbxEndTime.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s) + 1 + ":00");
    }
```

Comment: sT, sTimes, and sE all refer to the same object. If you remove an item it will be reflected in all references to that list.

Comment: @eddie_cat I see, how can I remove only from one list then?

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: @sgtBlueBird make a copy of the list like tolanj's answer explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> sT = sTimes;
```

Is the issue,

You want `List<string> sT = new List<string>(sTimes);`

Ie you want to manipulate a copy of your original list, not the list itself.